# Como mostrar en unas vista de Laravel, una consulta de datos obtenidas con un Task Scheduling(Tareas Programadas)

Tags: php, laravel, cronjobs

Con ayuda de Task Scheduling(Tareas Programadas) en el archivo ubicado en carpetaRaiz\app\Console\Kernel.php.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            $contratos = DB::table('contratos')->whereBetween('fin_contrato',[Carbon::today(),Carbon::today()->addDays(15)])->get();
            info($contratos);
        })->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

obtengo una consulta de datos que se muestras de manera iterativa en el archivo Laravel.log. La información que obtengo se muestra de la siguiente manera.

```
[2021-11-06 18:41:00] local.INFO: [{"id":73,"cargo":"Conductor","contrato":"S.T.C (2).pdf","tipo_contrato":"Termino Indefinido","jornada_laboral":"Medio Tiempo","sueldo":900000,"inicio_contrato":"2021-10-31","fin_contrato":"2021-11-06","id_empleado":1,"created_at":"2021-11-05 15:59:21","updated_at":"2021-11-05 15:59:21"}]
```

Como Puedo hacer uso de los atributos y datos que se muestran en el local.INFO. Mi idea es mostrar estos datos como notificaciones a los usuarios.

Nota: Espero haberme echo entender, no tengo mucha experiencia con la plataforma y con la programación en general.

De antemano Gracias.

Comment: Tal vez puedes usar tanto un [Event](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events) como un [Job](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#creating-jobs) cada que se llame a esa **Taks** y le pasas esos datos. Pero ¿de qué manera quieres usar esos datos exactamente?

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta. La idea es q se muestren por medio de un alert de bootstrap. Estoy intentando usar Events pero según lo que he visto es que hay que configurar también un Listener, es aquí donde no se como hacer uso del Taks.

Comment: Creo que deberías echarle un ojo a [esto](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#the-shouldbroadcast-interface), por otro lado creo que tu pregunta no cumple del todo con las reglas de SO; pero eso te puede funcionar